# Edit dict in string

Tags: python

I want to edit string data

```
ids = [12,34,56,78]
data = '{"id":999}'
```

I want to replace '999' with every id in and want output to be:

```
'{"id":12}'
'{"id":34}'
'{"id":56}'
'{"id":78}'
```

I tried with .format but it is not working.

Comment: "I tried with .format but it is not working." Show how you tried, and show what happened.

Comment: Can you please be able to Accept my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Hi you need to iterate over the array and replace the 999.

```
ids = [12,34,56,78]
data = '{"id":999}'

for i in ids:
    print(data.replace('999',str(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question completely, but I hope this code is helpful.

```
ids = [12,34,56,78]
data = '{"id":999}'
IDS = []
dataeval = eval(data)
for id in ids:
   dataeval["id"] = id
   IDS.append(str(dataeval))
```